# Display Burmease font in Java text area?

Tags: java, unicode

I am able to display Hindi, Malayalam fonts in `Jtext` area.

But when I was trying to display Burmease font, it's showing squares only. Is there any library jar to be added??

Answer (score 0):

Does the font used contain the Burmese characters? In this case you would only need to type Burmese in the text area to check that.

```
Font font = ...
textArea.setFont(font);
```

Comment: actually , my application will recieve the text in unicode format and also its dynamic . so i cant set the font statically

Comment: Then you need a full Unicode font. As Mon/Burmese is in Unicode quite late, since 1999, Unicode 3.0, try Myanmar1 (a specific font) too. These full Unicode font files are large files (20 MB - 36 MB). When stored with the application, `Font.createFont` may be used. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmic_scripts